# How do you make a side scrolling platform game for android in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, game-engine

I want to make a simple side-scrolling platform game inn eclipse that can be played on my galaxy s3. I cant find any videos on youtube. Can you guys give me instructions or a link on how to start my project?

Comment: Do you have Android knowledge/experience?

Answer (score 2):

Do a Google search for 'Replica Island'. It is a side-scrolling game developed by one of the guys at Google, and the source code is available online. 
He used OpenGL for rendering, but you could use a SurfaceView and Canvas instead.